# How can I save a captured picture from the user to the cosmos db in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

It's supposed that I allow the user to capture a picture using his camera or pick one from the gallery. 
I have a property called picture in the model which it's supposed to have the path of the image.
How can I save this image to the database and save its path in the property?

Comment: You have to serialize the data to a string so that it can be part of a json document. You can convert the image to Base64 encoding, but that is a misuse of Cosmos and will not index well. Since you are obviously already in Azure, you should store your images in Azure Blob Storage instead and just put the reference to them in your Cosmos documents.

Comment: You could store the image file as byte array to database. How did you pick or capture the picture? You could use the Xam.Plugin.Media plugin to achieve the function. The library provides the MediaFile.Path and  `GetStream` methods which could help to save the picture.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do it is to use a service like Azure Blob Storage, you can see details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/azure-services/azure-storage). But eventually, you will just convert the image to bytes, and then upload that to get back the URL:

```
byte[] byteData = Convert.ToByteArray(image);
var uploadedFilename = await AzureStorage.UploadFileAsync(ContainerType.Image, new MemoryStream(byteData));
```

The other less expensive way to do it, is to create your own server and have a web service that enables you to upload pictures to it, and return the URL of the image that you uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I save this image to the database and save its path in the property?

You could store the image file as byte array to database. How did you pick or capture the picture? You could use the [Xam.Plugin.Media plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) to achieve the function. The library provides the related method which could help to save the picture easily.

Try to use the `MediaFile.Path` command to get the path of the image file after picking a photo from the gallery.You could get the stream with `GetStream()` method and convert the stream to byte array. Then Store the byte[] and the path string in the database.

```
var image_file = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions() { });
var Image_stream = image_file.GetStream();
image_file.Dispose();

//convert the image stream to byte array
private byte[] GetImageBytes(Stream stream)
{
    byte[] ImageBytes;
    using (var memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        ImageBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
    return ImageBytes;
}
```